# How can I wait for variable to be set in a service-worker for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, variables, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I am building a Chrome Extension that does Speach-to-Text to a Google Document. In my service-worker I am receiving the processed text (via port messaging, so is periodic), so it can be sent to be written but I can also receive commands if the user wants to insert a new paragraph, create a bullet list, etc. When I recieve a command I have a function that manages it `checkCommand(currCommand);` that looks like this:

```
const checkCommand = (cmd) => {
const commands = {
    'foo command': () => {
        console.log('This command should create a bullet list');
        if(currListType !== null){
        callGoogleAPIScript(myToken, 'createBulletList',currListType);
        formatingMode = false;
        }
    },
    'bar command': () => {
        console.log('This command should create a new paragraph');
        callGoogleAPIScript(myToken, 'newParagraph');
        formatingMode = false;
    },
    
};
if (cmd && commands.hasOwnProperty(cmd)) {
    commands[cmd](); // needed [cmd] because split words
} else {
    console.log('Command dosen't exist');
    formatingMode = false;
}};
```

Note: formatingMode is used for the service-worker to know that the command has been executed and can continue dictation.
While *formatingMode !== false*, I am still receiving text, but now I want to set specific characteristics for my commands, for example, *currListType* that tells which bullet list the user chose (circle, number, etc.). How can I wait for this variable to be set in the program and then run *callGoogleAPIScript(myToken, 'createBulletList',currListType);*?
I've tried using a promise right before calling *callGoogleAPIScript* , something like this:

```
function waitUntilListTypeSet() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const checkListType = () => {
      if (currListType !== null) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        setTimeout(checkListType, 100);
      }
    };
    try {
      checkListType();
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

But from what I've read setTimeout is unreliable in service-worker + it doesn't work for some reason ( my *currListType* is set correctly globally, but promise blocks)

Comment: You *don't* wait for "the variable to be set". You should instead wait for the message (event) that sets the variable, or rather get rid of the variable altogether and just wait for the message value.

Comment: It's not the `setTimeout()` is unreliable. It's that [`setTimeout()` isn't supported in service workers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/to-service-workers/#convert-timers). There is a [`chrome.alarms` namespace](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/) that you can use.   Here's a [PR I just submitted](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/pull/6371) to make the example behind that first link a bit more meaningful.